# Missing the Calendar list view layout

Tags: list, calendar, view

After I build a Calendar I click create a Calendar leyers to build colored calendar. I click New Leyer/Kalendar:

[image]

And next I get a window, but without any list or list view. Please see below picture:

[image]

Nothing list and list show. Please help me how to choose list. Now they re empty.

Comment: I only want to do colored Calendar.

Comment: Do you have multiple calendar lists by the moment?

Comment: I don't know How to add them or erase them to Multiple ?

Comment: Click the button "Rozwiaz" to load the lists that are available to use as overlays. It should load at least your current calendar, next choose a view to show with a specific color. If the views dropdown are empty, you need to create additional views for your calendar list.

Comment: https://blog.metrostarsystems.com/2012/12/01/jennys-sharepoint-tip-color-coded-calendars-out-of-the-box-solution/

Answer (score 1):

User 19952 find a solution. First user must create a lot of views, because with defoult wiew it nothing show. And clicking button Rozwiąż show errors, before we don't create a View. After we create a View solution works.

Comment: This needs a bit elaboration, it is hard to understand the solution right now :)

Comment: I edited, meybe now it will work ;)

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out my posts here: http://davidlozzi.com/2012/01/26/color-code-your-sharepoint-calendar/ I walk through creating overlays, and making multiple views.

Comment: Please do not post link only answers, instead add details to your answer and use the link as a reference :)

Answer (score -1):

I just tried the `"Resolve"` button under `"Web URL"` and it worked.